# C# inherited method with some inherited logic and some custom logic - is that possible?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a C# application; There is a parent class with many child classes. I would like a method in the parent class with some logic in it, and have custom logic added to it by each child class, so that when any child class calls the method, it first runs some code defined in the parent class, and then runs the customized part of it as defined in the child class. Can this be done? If not, what is the best way to achieve this kind of code execution?

Comment: you could have a delegate, an abstract method, etc.

Comment: You could also call `base.Method()` from `Method()` in the child classes.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @itsme86 that's a better idea than any I've had so far. Though, it does require having that line of code repeated at the beginning of the method in every child class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve it is define a non virtual method as entry point that execute the code defined in the base class and then call a virtual (or abstract) protected method that child class can (or must) override, like this:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        //  some code defined in the parent class

        BarCore(); // the customized part of it as defined in the child class
    }

    protected virtual void BarCore() { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done by defining a virtual method in the base class, and calling it from your "payload" method at the spot where the custom logic needs to be "plugged in". It is common to make this method abstract:

```
abstract class MyBase {
    protected abstract void CustomLogic(); // Subclasses implement this
    public void PayloadMethod() {
        ... // Do somethig
        CustomLogic();
        ... // Do something else
    }
}

class Derived1 : MyBase {
    protected override void CustomLogic() {
        ... // Custom logic 1
    }
}

class Derived2 : MyBase {
    protected override void CustomLogic() {
        ... // Custom logic 2
    }
}

class Derived3 : MyBase {
    protected override void CustomLogic() {
        ... // Custom logic 3
    }
}
```

Clients of your class hierarchy instantiate one of `DerivedN` classes, and call `PayloadMethod()`, which calls `CustomLogic` as part of its invocation.

This approach is called [*Template Method Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to have two methods:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // base class code

        // derived class code, modifiable by the derived class
        this.DoItSpecificallyForThatDerivedClass();
    }

    protected abstract void DoItSpecificallyForThatDerivedClass();
}

public class ADerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void DoItSpecificallyForThatDerivedClass()
    {
        // code specific to this instance and/or class
    }
}
```